# Instanciar archivos en L5 Modular - Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Por medio de la librería **"artem-schander/l5-modular": "dev-master"** [https://github.com/Artem-Schander/L5Modular] instalada en el composer json, estoy ajustando mi proyecto para que sea modular y no mezclar todo en el (ver carpeta Modules/Informes en la imagen). Todo funciona correctamente pero quisiera que mis archivos JS, CSS y AJAX quedaran dentro del mismo modulo (En este caso **Informes**) así que decidí crear la carpeta public y dentro de ella las respectivas carpetas de js, css y ajax pero no consigo desde las vistas instanciar los archivos js y css

[image: Estructura de carpetas modulares]

Probé con

```
{!! Html::script('../../app/Modules/Informes/public/js/visorinforme.js'); !!}
```

Saliendo desde la carpeta public en la raíz e ingresando a public en el modulo
ó

```
<script src="../public/js/visorinforme.js"></script>
```

Pero con ninguna me funciona.
Quisiera saber si los archivos que están originalmente en la carpeta **public** de la raíz deben permancer allí o si puedo moverlos a la carpeta public en la nueva estructura modular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No** creo que los puedas mover, la idea de Laravel es precisamente aislar la carpeta public de las otras carpetas que contienen el código **importante** por seguridad, de esa manera mueves todo el código fuente de tu aplicación fuera del directorio **visible** al público y dejas los recursos estáticos (css, js, imágenes, etc.) y el punto de entrada (index.php) accesibles.

En Illuminate\Foundation\Application se especifica esta ruta por medio del método publicPath():

```
/**
 * Get the path to the public / web directory.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function publicPath()
{
    return $this->basePath.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'public';
}
```

Por lo cual creo que solo se puede tener una carpeta **public**, a menos que hagas una extensión importante del código de Laravel, lo cual no aconsejaría.